# Angular 6 how to make all input's Not editable element inside a form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Is there a way to disable and make all fields **non editable** 
`(input / mat-select / textfield / option/input/mat-checkbox etc)` inside a Form

by telling only the parent div name in Angular / Angular-material ?
(cannot editing them)

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './leaseholder.component.html'
})
export class LeaseholderComponent implements OnInit, IFormDirtyWarningComponent {

  leaseholderForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.createLeaseholderForm();
  }

  createLeaseholderForm() {
    this.leaseholderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      civility: [this.identityModel.civility],
      firstName: [this.identityModel.firstName, Validators.compose([Validators.pattern("[^\\d]+")])],
      lastName: [this.identityModel.lastName, Validators.compose([Validators.pattern("[^\\d]+")])],
      birthName: [this.identityModel.birthName, Validators.compose([Validators.pattern("[^\\d]+")])],
      birthDate: [this.identityModel.birthDate],
      birthPlace: [this.identityModel.birthPlace, Validators.compose([Validators.pattern("[^\\d]+")])],
      nationality: ['FR', this.identityModel.nationality],
      endOfStay: [this.identityModel.endOfStay]
    });
  }
```

---

```
    <form [formGroup]="leaseholderForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="mat-radio-group-inverted">
                    <mat-radio-group formControlName="civility">
                        <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="MR">M.</mat-radio-button>
                        <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="MME">MME.</mat-radio-button>
                    </mat-radio-group>
                </div>
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput upperCaseInput placeholder="Nom d'usage" formControlName="lastName">
                </mat-form-field>
...........................
..........  example
    </form>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using reactive form you can achieve this  programmatically like this (one-by-one approach):

```
 this.formGroupName.controls[controlNmae].disable();
```

Eg: `this.formGroupName.controls['lastName'].disable()`

To disable all at once:

```
this.formGroupName.disable()
```

In your case do: `this.leaseholderForm.disable()`
And to turn it back do: `this.leaseholderForm.enable()`

What you can do is create a function like this and call it after you have called `createLeaseholderForm()`:

```
disableForm() {
 this.leaseholderForm.disable()
}
```

for more info read [this](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

Comment: I agree. This should work, as shown [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hlqxqt). @AnouarMokhtari - No error in the console?

Comment: Keep in mind that a disabled <input> does not submit with the form, but a readonly <input> does.

Comment: Buenaso! that's what i need! Thank you!

Answer (score 33):

Disabled and not editable are not necessarily the same thing. A disabled input is of course also not editable, but it has a distinct appearance - greyed out and looks 'disabled'. A read-only input looks the same as a normal input, but is not editable. So you have to ask whether you want your controls actually disabled or just read-only.

If you just want read-only, you can simply use the `readonly` property of `<input>` and bind it to a variable in your controller. For example:

```
export class LeaseholderComponent implements OnInit, IFormDirtyWarningComponent {

    @Input() editable: boolean = false; // doesn't have to be an @Input
    ...
}

<form [formGroup]="leaseholderForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [readonly]="!editable" upperCaseInput placeholder="Nom d'usage" formControlName="lastName">
    </mat-form-field>
    ...
</form>
```

Note that the `editable` property doesn't need to be an `@Input`, but that could be useful if you are using the form as a reusable component and need to make the editable/read-only decision at the DOM level.

For other components like radio buttons, where no `readonly` property is available, you should probably rethink the layout. It might make more sense to use a different component to display the radio option in read-only mode, rather than the complete list of options. For example, use a label and value pair:

```
<div *ngIf="editable; else readonlyRadio" class="mat-radio-group-inverted">
    <mat-radio-group formControlName="civility">
        <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="MR">M.</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="MME">MME.</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</div>
<div #readonlyRadio>
    <label>Civility</label>
    <span>{{ leaseholderForm.controls['civility'].value }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best solution as it doesn't mark the field as invalid.

Answer (score 9):

Since **disabled** attribute doesn't work on some components, what I did is - I set the **pointer-events:none** on the css to cover all the components inside the div content.

**Here's my CSS code:**

```
.disabledDiv {
      pointer-events: none;
      opacity: 0.4;   }
```

**Here's my HTML:**

```
<div class="content-area" [ngClass]="{disabledDiv: !isActiveDiv}"> 
    <!-- other components here (input/select/etc.) -->
<div>
```

**And on my TS:**

```
editData() {
    this.isActiveDiv = true;
  }
```

Comment: Not familiar with pointer events. But does this prevent tabbing too?

Answer (score 1):

Create a FormGroup as explained here:

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#add-a-formgroup

Then, grab the `formGroup` instance programmatically and call `.disable()` on it, like this:

`this.leaseholderForm.disable()`

Comment: yes, i use reactive form , i update the issue. .disable() doesn't work

Comment: can you provide the code of your component controller?

Comment: Done, i am not sure , that .disable()  turn all fields of form Not editable , i think that disable a Control of form

Answer (score 1):

Use `disable` attribute in the html template.

```
           <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput upperCaseInput placeholder="Nom d'usage" formControlName="lastName" disable>
            </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: The disabled property should not be used with input elements in Angular reactive forms. The form control should be disabled instead:

`control = new FomrControl({'value', disabled: true}, [validators]);`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use readonly attribute in the HTML file inside the input tag.

Comment: Try not to use images of code to answer questions - code is text, why not post it as such?

Answer (score 1):

```
this.formGroupName.controls['lastName'].disable()
```

Did not work for me in Angular 8. So I made it work by adding a 'readonly' attribute inside the HTML and then change its value in .ts file.

**inside .html file**

```
 <input formControlName="email" matInput type="email" #email email="true" [readonly]="email_readonly" />
```

**inside .ts file**

```
email_readonly = false;

yourFunction()
{
  this.email_readonly = true;
}
```