# Conditionally disable button based on reactive form or input state

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I have a reactive form `trainingFeedbackForm` with a textarea:

```html
<textarea pInputTextarea appWhiteSpace inputField="{{not_attended_reason}}"
    [(ngModel)]="not_attended_reason" [disabled]="attended==='yes'"
    placeholder="The reason for not attending the traning"
    (inputValue)="removeWhitespace($event)"></textarea>
```

I want to disable this button when either the form is valid or the textarea is empty:

```html
<button (click)="getFeedbackFormValue()" class="btn-gradient fill-btn ripple"
    [disabled]="trainingFeedbackForm.invalid || !not_attended_reason">
    Submit feedback
</button>
```

The approach I am using above is not working.

How can I achieve this?  Can somebody help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable input on angular form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55569844/disable-input-on-angular-form)

Comment: You are not using reactive form in above code

Answer (score 0):

`component.html` in
Replace `disabled="checkDisbled()"` this

add `required` in  `<textarea required>`

```
<button (click)="getFeedbackFormValue()" class="btn-gradient fill-btn ripple"
                disabled="checkDisbled()">
                Submit feedback
              </button>
```

Add in `Component.ts`  file

```
checkDisbled(){
  if(this.trainingFeedbackForm.invalid){ // <- add number of validation
  return true;
  }
  else {
  return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, just added !trainingFeedbackForm.invalid

```
<button (click)="getFeedbackFormValue()" class="btn-gradient fill-btn ripple"
[disabled]="!trainingFeedbackForm.invalid">
Submit feedback
</button>
```

Also, make sure that you add Validators.required to each form in your .ts