# Angular mat-autocomplete disable input FormControl not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

I am working on a custom components library, and we have a custom autocomplete component with chips. I want to be able to disable the input control when the disabled property in config object is true. I tried to do that in ngOnInit, but it didn't work.
HTML

```
 <div [formGroup]="group" *ngIf="config && !config.hideInput">
    <label *ngIf="config.overLabel" style="font-weight: 500;">{{ config.overLabel }}</label>
      <mat-form-field class="form-input" [appearance]="config.appearance ? config.appearance : 'standard'">
        <mat-chip-list #chipList>
          <mat-icon *ngIf="config.showIconOnAutocomplete" class="material-icons-outlined positionAbsolute" [class]="config.iconOnAutocompleteClass ? config.iconOnAutocompleteClass : ''">{{ config.showIconOnAutocomplete ? config.iconOnAutocomplete : '' }}</mat-icon>
          <mat-chip
            [class]="config.styleClass"
            *ngFor="let option of (config.value ? config.value : options); let i = index"
            selectable="true"
            removable="true"
            (removed)="remove(option.value, i)"
          >
            {{ option.value }}
            <mat-icon *ngIf="!config.removeChipIcon && option.type === 'field' && !config.disabled" matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
          </mat-chip>
          <input
            #optionInput
            matInput
            type="text"
            [placeholder]="
              config.placeholder ? (config.placeholder | translate) : ''
            "
            [formControl]="optionCtrl"
            [matAutocomplete]="auto"
            [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
            [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
            (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
          />
        </mat-chip-list>
        <mat-autocomplete
          #auto="matAutocomplete"
          (optionSelected)="selected($event)"
          [displayWith]="functionFn"
        >
          <mat-option
            *ngFor="
              let option of filteredOptions | async;
              trackBy: trackByIndex
            "
            [value]="option"
          >
            {{
              config.fieldToShowAutocomplete
                ? option[config.fieldToShowAutocomplete]
                : option
            }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
        <errors-field-form
          [config]="config"
          [group]="group"
        ></errors-field-form>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

ts

```
export class FormAutocompleteMultiConditionsComponent implements Field, OnInit {
  separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];
  optionCtrl = new FormControl();
  @ViewChild('optionInput') optionInput!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  config!: AutocompleteConditionsFieldConfig;
  group!: FormGroup;
  listAutocompleteCopy: {type: 'field' | 'condition' | 'operator' | 'value'; value: string; isCompound?: boolean}[] | undefined = [];
  objectKeys = Object.keys;
  options: {type: 'field' | 'condition' | 'operator' | 'value'; value: string; isCompound?: boolean}[] = [];
  filteredOptions: Observable<any[] | undefined> | undefined;
  functionFn = this.displayFn.bind(this);

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.config.disabled) {
      this.optionCtrl.disable();
    }
    this.options = this.config.value;
    this.listAutocompleteCopy = this.config.listAutocomplete?.slice();
    this.filteredOptions = this.optionCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      debounceTime(150),
      map((value) => {
        if (value) {
          return typeof value === 'string' ||
            !this.config.fieldToShowAutocomplete
            ? value
            : value[this.config.fieldToShowAutocomplete];
        }
      }),
      map((field) =>
        field && this.listAutocompleteCopy ? this._filter(field, true) : []
      )
    );
  }
}
```

here is a demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uwnyev, as the ts code has more code than I have shown here.

Why `disable()` function in form control doesn't work?

Comment: There are two potential reasons why your condition is failing and not behaving as you expect. First, because the disabled property is undefined at the time your template is rendered. Second, the way you configure your control disabled property is not right and this is what  I expect. You can follow up on the link I will paste under this comment, that might help.

Comment: It seems your issue is a duplica of this one: [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840136/disable-input-fields-in-reactive-form)   
-Please provide a Stackblitz that might help as well-

Comment: Thank you for your reply. here is the code [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uwnyev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the input after the view is initialized. Otherwise, you're disabling a DOM element that hasn't been created yet.
Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4sdksw?file=src/app/form-autocomplete/form-autocomplete.component.ts).

```js
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.config.disabled) {
      this.optionCtrl.disable();
    }
  }
```